# How to convert a multi-key hash to single key hash in Ruby for Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts

I have this data in Ruby, for creating a barchart using Highcharts.js which requires the data in a JSON format:

```
data = {["January", "a"]=>54, ["January", "b"]=>13, ["January", "d"]=>2, ["January", "c"]=>1, 
        ["February", "a"]=>27, ["February", "b"]=>11, ["February", "c"]=>4, ["March", "a"]=>22, 
        ["March", "b"]=>11, ["March", "d"]=>2, ["March", "c"]=>2, ["April", "a"]=>32, 
        ["April", "b"]=>12, ["April", "d"]=>6, ["April", "c"]=>2, ["May", "a"]=>7, 
        ["May", "d"]=>3, ["June", "a"]=>5, ["July", "a"]=>25, 
        ["August", "a"]=>23, ["August", "d"]=>3, ["August", "c"]=>3, ["September", "a"]=>6}
```

The data is stored in a variable and is not coming from a file.

I want to convert this into a json object to send it to Highcharts for charting. I need the data in the following format:

```
category = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September"]

series: [{
            name: 'a',
            data: [54, 27, 22, 32, 7, 5, 25, 23, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'b',
            data: [13, 11, 11, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'c',
            data: [1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6]
        },
            {
            name: 'd',
            data: [2, 0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 3, 6]
        }]
```

The data is missing for some months, and sometimes not in alphabetical order.

Is there an easy way in Ruby to unlist the original Hash, and then extract the information out of it while filling the missing values with 0, and getting the JSON output as required?

p.s. :Tried converting the data.to_json but highcharts doesnt accept it in raw form. Is there any other way to create a bar chart using this data in Highcharts?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) gem for rendering HighCharts in our Controller itself.

So can easily customize data for your Charts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on what logic those zeros inside of the series data arrays are supposed to be inserted, but this might get you almost there:

```
def transform(data)
  hash = { :category => [], :series => [] }

  data.keys().reduce(hash) { |accum, key|
    month = key[0]
    letter = key[1]

    # Push month
    accum[:category].push(month) if !accum[:category].include?(month)

    # Find existing item in series or create new one
    existing = accum[:series].select { |item| item[:name] == letter }
    item = existing.length > 0 ? existing[0] : {:name => letter, :data => []}

    # Push the number value in item's data
    item[:data].push(data[key])

    # Collect item if not already in series array
    accum[:series].push(item) if existing.length == 0

    accum
  }
end

result = transform(MY_DATA_HERE)
result[:series].sort! {|a,b| a[:name] <=> b[:name] } # sort them!

puts result
```

Output:

```
{
  :category=>["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September"], 
  :series=>[
    {:name=>"a", :data=>[54, 27, 22, 32, 7, 5, 25, 23, 6]}, 
    {:name=>"b", :data=>[13, 11, 11, 12]}, 
    {:name=>"c", :data=>[1, 4, 2, 2, 3]}, 
    {:name=>"d", :data=>[2, 2, 6, 3, 3]}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catser = data.each_with_object(category: [], series: {}) do |(k, v), memo|
  memo[:category] << k.first
  (memo[:series][k.last] ||= []) << v
end
category, series = [
  catser[:category].uniq.sort,
  catser[:series].map { |k, v| { name: k, data: v } }
]
```